# How to use a variable in blade array

Tags: laravel-5.1

How can i use a variable inside a blade array like so

```
$my_var = 54

array('class'=>'info', 'link'=> '{{ $my_var }}', 'message'=> 'AllRenewals', 'icon'=> 'history')
```

Laravel seems to not be able to understand its a vairable

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$my_var = 54
```

array('class'=>'info', 'link'=> '{{ $my_var }}', 'message'=> 'AllRenewals', 'icon'=> 'history')

to

```
$my_var = 54
```

array('class'=>'info', 'link'=> {{ $my_var }}, 'message'=> 'AllRenewals', 'icon'=> 'history')

> don't use quotes if you want to access variables in laravel

Comment: I did try that, and apache threw error (PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 73400320 bytes) in Unknown on line 0) which make absolutely no sense to me.